# How to call "lexical this" or arrow syntax for this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to call myObj.sayHello with myObj as its running scope. I know about bind, and it works fine.

```
var myObj = {"name1":"BP",
         "sayHello":function(){
              console.log("Hello " + this.name1);
          }}

myObj.sayHello();

setTimeout(myObj.sayHello,2000);  //Hello undefined

setTimeout(myObj.sayHello.bind(myObj),2000);
```

My problem is in this approach,

```
setTimeout(() => myObj.sayHello, 2000);
```

What is wrong with this syntax. Please let me know and how to achieve => operator in my scenario.(i want to print Hello BP).

Comment: That's not JavaScript syntax (yet). You would use `function() { myObj.sayHello(); }` instead.

Comment: => is only valid in firefox, he is trying to use the ES6 [arrow functions](http://www.mdn.info/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions)

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes I cleverly edited my comment :)

Comment: Oops wrong link, [correct arrow functions doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions)

Comment: I was going through this video, Please refer what i want to say https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ4__W9nELc

Comment: @jforjs: Assuming you're using Firefox or some other implementation that supports the syntax, I've explained in my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22671167/3096782) where your error is. The fat arrow syntax isn't a `.bind()` method. You're actually creating and passing a fully separate function which gets invoked. Trouble is that the function you've created doesn't actually invoke the `.sayHello` method. It merely references it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably already know about which browsers do/don't support that syntax.

Given that, the problem in your code is that you're not invoking the `sayHello()` method.

```
//                             vv---invoke the function
setTimeout(() => myObj.sayHello(), 2000);
```

Otherwise the body of the function merely references `.sayHello` without invoking it.

Test it in Firefox, and you'll see it work.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have the fat arrow syntax in JavaScript, unfortunately. This source:

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/javascript-fat-city/

Says it's on the way though.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myObj.sayHello();
}
, 2000);
```